# How to fetch, update and render data in Vue app using axios?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to fetch data from the axios `get` request and then trying to update it from the response of another axios `get` request. However, I'm unable to render the data from the 2nd request.

The sample code extract is:

```
// api.js
  // fetch items - first api call
  fetchItems() {
    const ITEMS_ENDPOINT = `${ROOT_URL}/items`;
    return axios.get(ITEMS_ENDPOINT, config);
  },

  // fetch items info - 2nd api call
  fetchItemsInfo(itemId) {
    const ITEMS_INFO_ENDPOINT = `${ROOT_URL}/items/${itemId}`;
    return axios.get(ITEMS_INFO_ENDPOINT, config);
  },

// vue component
  methods: {
    async fetchItems() {
      const res = await api.fetchItems();
      this.items = res.data;
      console.log(this.items);
      // console output [{id:1, a:1}, {id:2, a:2}, {id:3, a:3}]
    },

    updateItems() {
      this.items.forEach(async (item) => {
          const itemId = item.id;
          const res = await api.fetchItemsInfo(itemId);
          const info = res.data;
          console.log(info);
          // console output {id:1, x:2}
          if (item.id === info.id) {
            item.x = info.x;
            console.log(item);
            // console output [{id:1, a:1, x:2}]
          }
      });
    },
  },

  async created() {
    await this.fetchItems();
    this.updateItems();
    console.log(this.items);
    // console output [{id:1, a:1, x:0}, {id:2, a:2, x:1}, {id:3, a:3, x:2}]
  },

// html
<ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <!-- out put is (only the data from 1st call is displayed): 
    1 || 1 ||
    2 || 2 ||
    3 || 3 ||
    -->
        {{ item.id }} || {{ item.a }} || {{ item.x }} 
      </li>
</ul>
```

Only the data from the 1st api call is being displayed, NOT from the 2nd call.
I can log the data from the `created` hook and it displays as expected in the console.
If I use a click (button click) method to call `updateItems` function then data renders as expected. However, I want the load it on page load.

I'm getting the same behavior even if I update the vuex state from the `updateItems` and render the state getters.

How can I render the data from the 2nd call as well?

many thanks

Comment: The issue is mostly with the forEach block you are using, can you try this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @ThakurKarthik no luck with `for..of` too.

Comment: I tried to make a small repro here https://jsbin.com/yuzuvoyefe/edit?html,js,console,output can you check it once if it is useful?

Comment: It's still not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're adding new properties to a reactive item.  This doesn't work.  I think this should work for you b/c you are re-creating the entire object instead of adding new properties

```
updateItems() {
  this.items = this.items.map(async item => {
    const { data: info } = await api.fetchItemsInfo(item.id);
    return {
      ...item,
      ...info
    }
  });
},
```

If you know the property names you could also use `Vue.set` if you wanted

```
Vue.set(item, 'property1', info.property1)
Vue.set(item, 'property2', info.property2)
etc...
```

I think this will do what you asked, but I also think just adding the details to the response of the fetch items call would be far less expensive than making an additional request per item.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from Thakur Karthik, I could find a workaround.
I changed `forEach` to `for..of` loop, created a new array in data, and finally copy the `this.items` to the new array. The updated part of the code is:

```
// .... 
    async updateItems() {
      for (const item of this.items) {
        const itemId = item.id;
        const res = await api.fetchItemsInfo(itemId);
        const info = res.data;
        console.log(info);
        // console output {id:1, x:2}

        if (item.id === info.id) {
          item.x = info.x;
          console.log(item);
          // console output [{id:1, a:1, x:2}]
        }
        // create a new array and copy items to it
        this.updatedItems = this.items;
      }
```

The second solution that I could find out is to call Vuex store action to update the state of items instead of copying. The above code will be:

```
    async updateItems() {
     
        //.... rest of the code

        // call a vuex store action (`setItems`) to update the state items
        this.setItems(this.items)
      }
```